# Update record in custom Object and Table

Tags: apex, custom-object, update, pageblocktable

I have a table that is populated from values from a custom object. For each record, I have an `<apex:inputField>` that shows the Quantity value for a record and the user is able to modify the value. There is a `<apex:commandButton>` that calls an APEX function to update the value. I rerender the field but the value does not update anywhere. Attached is the code for the APEX and the VF.

VF Code:

```
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable id="VAN_TABLE" value="{!outSku}" var="VAN"  style="table">
<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">VAN Type</apex:facet>
<apex:outputText value="{!VAN.VANType__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">Item Code</apex:facet>
<apex:outputText value="{!VAN.Item_Code__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">Item Description</apex:facet>
<apex:outputText value="{!VAN.ItemDescription__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">Quantity Needed</apex:facet>
<apex:inputField id="newQ" value="{!VAN.Quantity__c}"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!retrieve}" rerender="newQ" value="SUBMIT">
    <apex:param name="singleID" value="{!VAN.Item_Code__c}"/>
    <apex:param name="singleQ" value="{!VAN.Quantity__c}"/>
</apex:commandButton>

</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:commandButton action="{!retrieve}" rerender="VAN_TABLE" value="GET MY LIST!" />

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
```

The APEX code:

public class ProductByVan{

```
// The action function parameter gets set here - this is the input
//public String skey {get; set;}

// The output is set here so it can be re-rendered into the page
public List<VAN__c> outSku {get; set;}

public PageReference retrieve() {
   // TODO why is this only returning on and anarbitrary one at that?
   // Pass in the skey via a bind variable
   List<VAN__c> skus = [
           select Item_Code__c, VANType__c, ItemDescription__c, Quantity__c
           from VAN__c
           where VANType__c = 'ALBAIK'
           ];
   // Pass out the value
   outSku = skus;
   return null;
 }
public void setValue() {
  String itemID = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('singleID');
  Decimal newQ = Decimal.valueOf(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('singleQ'));
  List<VAN__C> updateQ = [select Quantity__c from VAN__c where Item_Code__c = 'itemID'];
  if (!updateQ.isEmpty()) {
  VAN__c item = updateQ[0];
  item.Quantity__c = newQ;
  update item;
  }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!retrieve}" rerender="newQ" value="SUBMIT">
    <apex:param name="singleID" value="{!VAN.Item_Code__c}"/>
    <apex:param name="singleQ" value="{!VAN.Quantity__c}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

I believe you meant to use setValue on this specific button? like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!setValue}" rerender="newQ" value="SUBMIT">
        <apex:param name="singleID" value="{!VAN.Item_Code__c}"/>
        <apex:param name="singleQ" value="{!VAN.Quantity__c}"/>
    </apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: I changed the method (silly mistake) but now I am getting an invalid decimal even after regex and parsing of the string. Invalid decimal:
Error is in expression '{!setValue}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page custorder: Class.ProductByVan.setValue: line 24, column 1